# java.sql.SQLException: No value specified for parameter 4

Tags: java, jdbc

I have here my code for inserting MCQ but when I click to submit it I'm getting an error while calling the method below

```
public static void add_question(Question question) {
        Connection cnx;
        try {

            cnx = Connect.getConnection();
            cnx.setAutoCommit(false);

            String req = "insert into question(title, contenu, proposition, reponse) values(?,?,?,?)";

            PreparedStatement st = cnx.prepareStatement(req);
            st.setString(1, question.getTitle());
            st.setString(2, question.getContenu());

            for (Proposition prop : question.getListProp()) {
                st.setString(3, prop.getContenu());

                st.addBatch(); 
            }

            for (Correct corr : question.getReponse()) {
                st.setString(4, corr.getCorrect());

                st.addBatch();
            }

            st.executeBatch();
            cnx.commit();
}
```

how to solve this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When `st.addBatch()` is executed, **ALL** parameters must be already set.

It's not the case in your code, since parameter #4 is not yet set in the first `st.addBatch()` when you are setting [multiple] parameters #3. You need to get those loops straight.

Comment: ah I see, thanks. in my application I have a checkbox that indicates which propositions are right 
when I inserted the values I realised that inserts it in front of the right and the wrong proposition. could u help me fix it

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can just do the below:

```
public static void add_question(Question question) {
        Connection cnx;
        try {

            cnx = Connect.getConnection();
            cnx.setAutoCommit(false);

            String req = "insert into question(title, contenu, proposition, reponse) values(?,?,?,?)";

            PreparedStatement st = cnx.prepareStatement(req);
            st.setString(1, question.getTitle());
            st.setString(2, question.getContenu());

            for (Proposition prop : question.getListProp()) {
                st.setString(3, prop.getContenu());
            }

            for (Correct corr : question.getReponse()) {
                st.setString(4, corr.getCorrect());
            }
            st.addBatch(); 
            st.executeBatch();
            cnx.commit();
}
```